# how to call an ajax url when a checkbox is selected

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery what is the best way to call a URL Via ajax and update a `<ul>` list with the data that is returned?  While the data is being fetched from the url, I would also like to show a "loading" spinner.

the URL is local to my application and will return back a json response.  When the checkbox is checkmarked, I'd like to call the URL and pass a parameter.  e.g. `/return/students?q=someparm`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be possible with [change](http://api.jquery.com/change/) event
The code could look somehow like this:

```
$('#checkboxId').change(function() {
   $.ajax({
      url: "/return/students?q=someparm",
      success: function(data){
         // modify list based on data
      }
   });
   // code to show loading spinner (is executed instantly after ajax request,
   // not waiting for success to be executed)
});
```

Comment: should I use $.ajax() function?

Comment: how would I show the loading spinner image for the time it takes to fetch the request?

Comment: depends what your loading spinner looks like. For example it could be a gif image which is not visible by default and you can set it visible while loading

Answer (score 0):

```
<span class="spinner" style="display: none"><img src="spinner.gif" /></span>

$('#checkboxId').change(function() {
   $('spinner').show();
   $.ajax({
      url: "/return/students?q=someparm",
      success: function(data){
         // modify list based on data
      },
      complete: function(){ $('spinner').hide(); }
   });
   // code to show loading spinner (is executed instantly after ajax request,
   // not waiting for success to be executed)
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/hide/

http://api.jquery.com/show/